# IAM CodeBuild policy condition - principal tag equals resource tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

**Goal:**

Create an IAM role policy that allows the role to perform defined actions on aws resources only if the role tag equals the resource tag.

For example:

IAM tag:

foo=bar

CodeBuild project tag:

foo=bar

IAM role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:List*",
                "codebuild:DescribeTestCases",
                "codebuild:DescribeCodeCoverages",
                "codebuild:BatchGet*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/foo": "${aws:PrincipalTag/foo}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When the user assumes the role, the user is denied access to `codebuild:ListProjects` on projects that have the same `foo=bar` key pair as the role within the AWS console and AWS CLI.

AWS console error:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/example-role/example-user is not authorized to perform: codebuild:ListProjects
```

AWS CLI error using the command: `aws codebuild list-projects --profile test`

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListProjects operation: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/example-role/botocore-session-59458209 is not authorized to perform: codebuild:ListProjects
```

Attempts:

**#1**

Use actual key pair value in policy condition:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:List*",
                "codebuild:DescribeTestCases",
                "codebuild:DescribeCodeCoverages",
                "codebuild:BatchGet*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/foo": "bar"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Result to `codebuild:ListProjects` access denied error on aws console

**#2**

Remove aws key brackets from `aws:PrincipalTag/foo`(shooting from the hip here)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:List*",
                "codebuild:DescribeTestCases",
                "codebuild:DescribeCodeCoverages",
                "codebuild:BatchGet*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/foo": "aws:PrincipalTag/foo"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**#3**

Used the resource type within the resource tag condition `codebuild:ResourceTag/foo`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:List*",
                "codebuild:DescribeTestCases",
                "codebuild:DescribeCodeCoverages",
                "codebuild:BatchGet*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "codebuild:ResourceTag/foo": "${aws:PrincipalTag/foo}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Same `codebuild:ListProjects` access denied error on aws console

Comment: Aws cli also results in access denied? Or is it only for aws console?

Comment: @Marcin Access denied in both AWS console and CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html):

> CodeBuild supports authorization based on tags for **project-based actions**

I think [ListProjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_ListProjects.html) action is not project-based. It is for entire codebuild, rather then for a specific project.

Comment: thank you for the link and clear explanation. I've made changes to the role policy regarding codebuild. Although when I moved on to defining AWS Athena statements, I'm getting access denied errors again (see UPDATE section of post)

Comment: I see your point. I was thinking since the post title was "IAM role policy condition - principal tag equals resource tag", I could squeeze in Athena into the post description. I'll update the post title and description to be specifically about CB IAM policy conditions.